# Php redirect to another page

Tags: php, redirect

I tried using different techniques and saw other people using this method. I dont understand why mine isn't working. It only redirects to the first "if" conditon

```
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

$sql2= "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' ";
$sql3="SELECT usertype from `user` WHERE username='$username'";
//$result = $con->query($sql2);

$result=mysqli_query($conmfadb,$sql2);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result); 
#echo $count;  
//Query to redirect
$pageSelect=mysqli_query($conmfadb,$sql3);
// If result matched $mail and $pwd, table row must be 1 row
if($pageSelect="admin"){

 echo"
<script type='text/javascript'>location.href = 'menu.php';</script>";    


} elseif($pageSelect="user"){
    if ($count >= 1) {

  echo"
<script type='text/javascript'>location.href = 'form/form.php';</script>";    
} else {
    echo "Your attempt is Unsuccessful! $count";
}
}
else
{
    echo"error";
}`
```

Comment: Argh. Use PHP `header` redirects.

Comment: Try `header` function instead or use `window.location.href`

Comment: Both aren't working

Comment: Your first if is always true because you make a declaration with tihs code if($pageSelect="admin") so use if($pageSelect == "admin")

Comment: when i do this my else statement giving "error " executes

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: else
{
    echo"error";
}
this condition executes

Comment: 1.Don't store plaintext passwords in your database. 2.`if ($count >= 1) {` Do you have more than one user with the same username/password combination? 3.`usertype` is already available from `$sql2`, no need for `$sql3`. 4.`echo` or `var_dump` `$pageSelect` after you declare it and see if it holds the value you think it holds.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this below . It's working

```
if($pageSelect="admin")
{

?>
<script type='text/javascript'>location.href = 'menu.php';</script>";    
<?php

} 

elseif($pageSelect="user")

{
    if ($count >= 1) {

 ?>
<script type='text/javascript'>location.href = 'form/form.php';</script>";   
<?php 
} 

else {

        echo "Your attempt is Unsuccessful! $count";
    }
}
else
{
    echo"error";
}
```

Comment: the whole code is in the php tag . how does this differ things?

Comment: In the php file you have used script. so that close the php tag then process the script

Comment: Still assigning in your `if`s, not comparing

Comment: The real issue is the `if($pageSelect="admin")` line. This solution just copies that error!

Comment: It's @KhwajaHussamQuasmi given code i have just providing redirect suggestion only. Yes if condition is not defined properly.

Comment: tried it , its not working . when i do the assignment my my else statement giving "error" executes